# Jquery Click() Error - Out of stack space

Tags: jquery, click

Okay, I'm stumped here. I have a control that is comprised of a table.  I am allowing the user to click the hyperlink in the bottom row to go directly to the associated view.

On  the other hand, the user can click anywhere else inside the table and a selection is made. This selection activates a tool bar that allows the user to perform some tasks on the selected item. If the user clicks the selected item again, I want to programatically click the hyperlink.  But when I run the jQuery for programatically clicking a hyperlink, I keep getting the "Out of stack space" error.  I'm fully aware that the click event is being called recursively but I have not idea of how to prevent it! Here's my code...

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.mouseOver, .mouseOut, .selected
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.mouseOver
{
    border: solid thin #99defd;
    background: #e9f8fe;
}
.mouseOut
{
    border: solid thin White;
}
.selected
{
    border: solid thin #e0a403;
    background: #f8f4de;
}
</style>

<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $items = $('.mouseOut');
        $items.mouseenter(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('class') != 'selected')
                $(this).attr('class', 'mouseOver');
        });
        $items.mouseleave(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('class') != 'selected')
                $(this).attr('class', 'mouseOut');
        });

        $items.click(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('class') == 'selected') {
                $(this).find('a').click();
            }
            else {
                $('.selected').attr('class', 'mouseOut');
                $(this).attr('class', 'selected');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table cellpadding="5" class="mouseOut">
            <tr>
                <td>
                user module thumbnail...
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="A1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ControlPanelHost1$cphCtrl0$lvCollectionView$ctrl0$lnkBtn','')">Users</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table cellpadding="5" class="mouseOut">
            <tr>
                <td>
                stats module thumbnail...
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="A2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ControlPanelHost1$cphCtrl0$lvCollectionView$ctrl1$lnkBtn','')">Stats</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

This stripped out version will demonstrate the issue fully. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: What is this mess `(function($) { $(document).ready(function() {`?

Comment: @j08691, it's a closure. It only looks like a mess because the code is not indented.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, what is the purpose of wrapping a closure around the ready() call like this?

Comment: @Dave, it's an alternative to `jQuery(function($) {});` when jQuery runs in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some strange reason this solution works.

Replace:

```
$(this).find('a').click();
```

with:

```
window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

The code that Frédéric Hamidi provided was great but the click() was never posting back to the server.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that triggering the `click` event on an element's descendant also triggers it on that element, because the event bubbles up the DOM tree. Since your code triggers a descendant's `click` event while handling the very same event on its ancestor, infinite recursion ensues.

A way to work around this problem would be to use [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation) in order to prevent the `click` events triggered on your hyperlinks from bubbling up:

```
$(this).find("a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**EDIT:** However, the code above won't work as expected since your logic also resides in the ancestor's event handler. We can switch our approach on the problem and use [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) with [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to trigger a `click` event on the descendant hyperlink only if the event we're currently handling was triggered either on the ancestor element, or on a descendant which is not a hyperlink itself:

```
$items.click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'selected' && !$(event.target).is("a")) {
        $(this).find('a').click();
    } else {
        $('.selected').attr('class', 'mouseOut');
        $(this).attr('class', 'selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the post. The "Out of stack space" error is now gone but the click event is not getting proccessed.  I've added the code that you posted and added: $(this).find('a').click() below it. In debugging, the click event fires and the event handler that you wrote, proccesses the e.stopPropagation();  However, this is where nothing happens afterwards.

Comment: Ah, silly me, that's because your logic also resides in the ancestor's `click` event. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh the aggravation! That works as well concerning the "Out of stack space" error but nothing is still happening.  Judging from your excellent pieces of code, I won't be able to bind a click event for the entire table.  I may just have to leave the 'a' tag's containing row alone when binding the click event.

Comment: Okay, I just replaced: $(this).find('a').click() with window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href') and it works!!!  No more aspirin required! Lol. Thanks Frédéric for all your help.

Comment: This wasn't the direct solution to my problem but the explanation of what was happening helped me identify what was wrong with my code.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

it seems function __doPostBack is undefined , that may be the cause of your error